# ERRO LNK 2019 - Como resolver?

Tags: c

Estou tendo problema com o Visual Studio 2017.

Aparece isso quando vou compilar:

> LNK2019   símbolo externo indefinido _WinMain@16 referenciado na função "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) Win32Project2

Esse foi o código que eu escrevi, simples só para começar e testar se tudo estava ok.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n = 0;


    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa marcar o teu projeto como Console Application. É interessante ler essas duas referencias: [Creating a Console Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46e82t5z.aspx) e [Walkthrough: Creating a Standard C++ Program (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx).

Existe uma resposta no SO [Is it possible to convert a Win32 application project into a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009989/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-win32-application-project-into-a-console-application). A mais votada sugere alterar o linker para o `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` e mudar a macro de compilação de `_WINDOWS` para `_CONSOLE`.

Comment: Onde consigo alterar isso?

Comment: Eu uso Ubuntu. Não consigo ver aqui, mas eu vou procurar uma imagem para você.

Comment: Achei uma referencia no SO [Is it possible to convert a Win32 application project into a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009989/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-win32-application-project-into-a-console-application)

Comment: Mais rápido e fácil é apagar o projeto e criar um novo, por enquanto.